# django - DecimalField max_digits, decimal_places explained

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I'm just starting out with Django and using it to store forex prices which are represented as `1.21242`, `1.20641`, etc...

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ForexPrice(models.Model):
    openPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=6)
    highPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=6)
    lowPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=6)
    closePrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=6)
```

**My Question Is:**
How do the max_digits and decimal_places attributes work? I'm using 6 for both fields assuming `max_digits=6` will allow values to be stored up to 6 digits ie: 123456.000000 while `decimal_palces=6` will support values up to 000000.123456. 
Is this assumption correct or am I missing something?

Getting the following error when I save the record to the DB:

> A field with precision 6, scale 6 must round to an absolute value less
> than 1.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for sharing the resource. Yes, I saw their documentation however the example they provided didn't make sense to me until I saw KKAs answer below.

Answer (score 31):

`max_digits` must be equal, or higher than `decimal_places`.

If you were to have **123456.654321** you'd have to define `max_digits=12`, `decimal_places=6`.

`max_digits` is INCLUDING `decimal_places`.

Comment: Ahh... I see. That actually makes more sense now. So if I wanted to support something like 9.123456 I would use max_digits=7, decimal_places=6? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

"max_digits" represents the number of digits **all** of your numbers.

"decimal_places" represents the number of digits to the **right** of the comma.

For ex: to store numbers up to *999.99* with a resolution of 2 decimal places, you’d use:

models.DecimalField(..., **max_digits=5**, **decimal_places=2**)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple analysis

For the below expression in your model:

```
number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Here is the test & result

```
=> 9999.99 (correct)
=> 99999.99 (error: Ensure that there are no more than 6 digits in total) 
=> 9999.999 (error: Ensure that there are no more than 6 digits in total)
=> 999.999 (error: Ensure that there are no more than 2 decimal places)
=> 99999.9 (error: Ensure that there are no more than 4 digits before the decimal point)
```

So, the above example shows that if we use `max_digits=6`, you can enter total 6 digits as a field value.

As we have used `decimal_places=2`, we have to think that we can store two decimal places as values, and the rest `6-2 = 4` will be the number of digits before the point.

In the case of:

```
number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

We can store two decimal places as values, and the rest of `5-2 = 3` will be the number of digits before the point.